# Login with google account and get all profile info using Google api

Tags: php

As I am trying to login with google account and get the info of that logged in info but I am getting the error.

This is my code,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret_gmail.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
 $_SESSION['access_token'];
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($_SESSION['access_token']);
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
  $files = $drive->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();
  echo json_encode($files);
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/api/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

and the response is,

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
     {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient Permission"
     }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting METADATA permission. you need DRIVE_READONLY not DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY

```
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY );
```

FYI [google official documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/DriveScopes.html#DRIVE_SCRIPTS)

Comment: Thank you Wils for replying, I have added this scope too but still getting the same error. .

Comment: for the sack of testing, you should try gain a master permission like DRIVE. and then scope it down to the permission you actually needed.keep us updated.

Comment: Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}

Comment: Make sure the  access token is not expired. Request it again with OAuth.

Comment: getting Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}

Comment: what exactly i want is 1) user login in my site "Login with Google Account (Gmail)". 2)I have to get the basic info this logged in user from google account and save my database..

Comment: So do you see the Auth dialogue requesting the google Drive permission?

Comment: Not yet. I have done the calendar api and its working fine only not able to get info of logged in user..

Comment: $oauthService = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$userInfo = $oauthService->userinfo_v2_me->get();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($userInfo);
die;